# Почему в $_POST[name''] значение NULL?

Tags: php

В чем проблема? Я не правильно передаю? Как правильно передать?   `var_dump($name);`

---

```
$name      = $_POST['First'];
$last_name = $_POST['Last'];         
$phones    = $_POST["Telephone"]; 

var_dump($name);
```

---

```
   function add_ajax_rquest() {

      var  fn    = document.getElementById('fn').value;
      var  ln    = document.getElementById('ln').value;
      var  phone =  document.getElementById('phone').value;

      var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

      request.open("POST", 'regist.php', true);

      request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      request.send(fn, ln, phone); //передача переменной

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
      }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Не говоря о том, что параметр в `send` должен быть один, в Вашем клиентском коде не содержится никаких указаний на то, под какими ключами серверный код сможет обнаружить в запросе передаваемые значения.

```
request.send("First=" + encodeURIComponent(fn) + "&Last=" + ...);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript